# Compute the minimum or lower bound for required gates

Tags: optimization

In the problem, we have a certain number of flights that the occupation time (in minutes) of each flight in the gate is determined and considered as a parameter (i.e. flight 1 occupies the gate for 50 minutes, flight 2 occupies the gate for 60 minutes , and ...).
The available time for the gates are 1440 minutes. 
Based on occupation times of flights in a gate and available time for the gates, I want to compute the minimum required gates. 
Do you know a method or article to solve this problem?

Comment: This is an NP-Hard problem ... you probably are better off using heuristics.

Comment: Yes, it is in NP-Hard class problem. I looked for the heuristics but I couldn't find any method. The heuristics for the similar problem can help me.

Comment: Try using the space filling heuristic for boxes. Your "space" is time.